# 9 Patch image as splash screen issue with Cordova 3.6.3 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, nine-patch

I am using 9-patch image with the following dimensions as my splash screen for Android project built using Cordova 3.6.3.

LDPI:
Portrait: 200x320px
Landscape: 320x200px
MDPI:
Portrait: 320x480px
Landscape: 480x320px
HDPI:
Portrait: 480x800px
Landscape: 800x480px
XHDPI:
Portrait: 720px1280px
Landscape: 1280x720px

I am using the splashscreen plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) to control hiding of the splash screen after html content is loaded. All the configuration and implementation is working fine with non 9-patch images. When I am using 9-patch images the splash screen is not hiding and I am getting my start page HTML rendered in a smaller area in the middle of the splash screen image.

Please help me out to identify and solve the issue.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: "the splash screen is not hiding", are you calling `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` ? you have a console error?

Comment: I am calling navigator.splashscreen.hide() and the behavior is fine with png as aplash screen. When I use 9patch images all going wrong. I do not have any error in concole.